# Unable to debug android app on target

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to create a new app with Eclipse.  Things seem to work fine if I run through the emulator, but I cannot deploy it to my phone.

I have an original Motorola Droid, rooted running Gingerbread.

In the console, I get:

```
    [2011-05-30 15:13:30 - MapsDemo] ------------------------------
    [2011-05-30 15:13:30 - MapsDemo] Android Launch!
    [2011-05-30 15:13:30 - MapsDemo] adb is running normally.
    [2011-05-30 15:13:30 - MapsDemo] Performing com.example.android.apis.MapsDemo activity launch
    [2011-05-30 15:13:30 - MapsDemo] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
    [2011-05-30 15:13:34 - MapsDemo] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
    [2011-05-30 15:13:34 - MapsDemo] Device API version is 10 (Android
2.3.4)
    [2011-05-30 15:13:34 - MapsDemo] Uploading MapsDemo.apk onto device '0403626109009013'
    [2011-05-30 15:13:35 - MapsDemo] Installing MapsDemo.apk...
    [2011-05-30 15:13:35 - MapsDemo] Success!
    [2011-05-30 15:13:35 - MapsDemo] Starting activity com.example.android.apis.MapsDemo on device 0403626109009013
```

And in logcat I get:

```
05-30 15:30:11.922: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5718): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-30 15:30:11.922: INFO/AndroidRuntime(5718): Heap size: -Xmx40m
05-30 15:30:11.922: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5718): CheckJNI is OFF
05-30 15:30:11.922: WARN/dalvikvm(5718): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
05-30 15:30:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5718): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
05-30 15:30:12.164: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5721): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-30 15:30:12.164: INFO/AndroidRuntime(5721): Heap size: -Xmx40m
05-30 15:30:12.164: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5721): CheckJNI is OFF
05-30 15:30:12.164: WARN/dalvikvm(5721): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
05-30 15:30:12.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5721): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
05-30 15:30:12.406: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5725): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-30 15:30:12.406: INFO/AndroidRuntime(5725): Heap size: -Xmx40m
05-30 15:30:12.406: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5725): CheckJNI is OFF
05-30 15:30:12.406: WARN/dalvikvm(5725): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
05-30 15:30:12.406: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5725): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
```

When I look on my phone, it doesn't seem like it is actually uploading the apk, even though it says it succeeded.

What have I done wrong?  I tried searching for solutions, but I haven't had much luck...

Comment: I'm puzzled, is it failing to dexopt the apk, or failing to run it?  I think that a runtime start only happens for dexopting, while the "run" is done in a vm forked off of zygote.

Comment: If you get some other random apk from an alternative market or open source project build, can you adb install that with success?  If not, I suspect something is broken in your rooted configuration/alternative android build.  Oh, you could also try launching the app from the launcher - I find eclipse's ability to start things is imperfectly reliable.

Comment: Chris, that was it.  My stupid custom ROM was the problem.  I went back to the stock rom and things seem to work great!

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable `USB Debug` and install from `Unknown Sources` on your Android device?

Comment: Unknown sources is not relevant to USB installs, and it's relatively unlikely that this logcat dump was obtained autonomously on the phone rather than via usb debugging (ie, adb).

Comment: Yeah, unknown sources and USB debugging are both enabled.  Although, I don't know if it's releant, but when I unplug the cable it doesn't seem to notice that the USB connection is lost...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the **android:debuggable="true"** in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:debuggable="true" android:name=".MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: that gives a compile error, saying that you shouldn't hardcode that and you should let the application decide